# How can I do to integrate in my web page a pdf file that could be download by someone else?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with laravel.I want to put downloadable document on my web page.Can someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it explains more? For example, do you need only certain users to access the PDF or everyone can download? Can't you just upload it to your server and have it downloaded via a link?  For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you're looking to embed the PDF instead of just having a download link, can you use an `iframe` to embed the PDF?  The default embedded PDF viewer should have the ability for users to download the document.  Example: https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085

Comment: I want to allow everyone to download a file. I need to give access to the users to download the pdf  via a link but i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

To download `PDF` file from your Laravel project, you may use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf It will allow to download both static and dynamic content to download from your website as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to render it using laravel? or is it already available for download?

If you need to render it I suggest you use laravel dompdf as stated by the first comment.

If you already have the pdf try this:

```
<a href="{{asset('yourfolder/YourPDF.pdf')}}" download="{{asset('yourfolder/YourPDF.pdf')}}" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

It works for me